# Expected value of function of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It is known that $\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y)) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f(i,j)P(X=i,Y=j)$. How do I show that this indeed fits the usual definition of expected value, that is to say, it equals $\displaystyle\sum_{t \in \Omega} f(X(t),Y(t))P(t)$. The proofs that use the usual summation (/integral in case of continuity) are OK; I'm more interested in a proof that deals with Indicator functions. For clarity, $X,Y$ used here are random variables taking non-negative integer values, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\mathbb{E}(|X,Y|)$ is finite and $\Omega$ is obviously the probability space.

Comment: there is a proof in [it wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), in your case just set $Z:=(X,Y)$

Comment: Seems good. I still don't understand how to interpret it in terms of indicator functions.